# How can I fix my Chinese PDF parsed in Apache Tika for Python to read the characters correctly?

Tags: python, pdf, character-encoding, apache-tika

I have a downloaded PDF in Chinese that I want to extract text from using Tika + Python (the original link to the full PDF can be found [here](http://93.174.95.29/main/2617000/e486c2b1503e29312ab006fd396ed842/%28%E5%BD%93%E4%BB%A3%E7%BB%8F%E6%B5%8E%E5%AD%A6%E6%95%99%E5%AD%A6%E5%8F%82%E8%80%83%E4%B9%A6%E7%B3%BB%29%20%E8%BF%88%E5%85%8B%E5%B0%94%E3%83%BB%E6%A2%85%E5%B0%94%E6%96%87_%E6%AC%A7%E9%98%B3%E5%90%91%E5%86%9B_%E4%BF%9E%E5%BF%97%E6%9A%96%20-%20%E5%9B%BD%E9%99%85%E8%B4%A7%E5%B8%81%E4%B8%8E%E9%87%91%E8%9E%8D-%E4%B8%8A%E6%B5%B7%E4%BA%BA%E6%B0%91%E5%87%BA%E7%89%88%E7%A4%BE%20%281997%29.pdf), or an extracted sample page can be found [here](http://www.filedropper.com/testpage_3)).

When I ran the following code

```
analysed_file = 'D:\\5_Programming\\test.pdf'

# Parse data from file
file_data = parser.from_file(analysed_file, "http://localhost:9998/")

# Get files text content
text = file_data['content']
print(text)
```

it printed hollow boxes in the command line. When I copy those boxes and paste a sample here it looks like

```
£Î £á £÷ £á £ú £¬ £ó £è £õ £ê £á ÄÇ Íß ×È £¬ Êæ ¼Ó

£Ï £æ £æ £é £ã £å £ò £¬ £Ì £® £È £® °Â ·Æ Éª £¬ £Ì £® £È £®

£Ð £á £õ £ì £ó £¬ £Â £® £Ä £é £á £î £å ±£ ¶û Ë¹ £¬ £Â £® ÷ì °² ÄÈ
```

I created a PDF using latin characters and parsed it using the exact same script and it printed completely fine in the command line.

I opened the file in Acrobat to troubleshoot and it gave me the error message that it "Cannot find or create the font [[garbled characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g63vd.jpg)]". It also [displayed all characters as bullets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYJ3Q.jpg), which is its apparent behaviour if it doesn't recognise the font (https://helpx.adobe.com/au/acrobat/using/pdf-fonts.html):

[image]

However, in the Google Chrome PDF viewer the entire text is being [displayed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V9ml.jpg) in Chinese.

[image]

What is Google Chrome doing differently that allows it to be read while it appears garbled in Adobe Acrobat and Tika + Python, and how might I fix this issue with the PDF to allow Tika to parse it correctly? Is it an encoding or font issue? I am not directly concerned with it printing correctly in Acrobat.

Comment: Could it be an issue with your output encoding when you print? If you type a few chinese characters into your python program and print those out too, do they show up correctly?

Comment: @Gagravarr Yes, I have been working with Chinese for a bit now and it consistently shows up correctly in the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Apache Tika together with the Google Tesseract Parser started as a docker image - [blog post](https://medium.com/@masreis/text-extraction-and-ocr-with-apache-tika-302464895e5f)

Then You have to add the proper language in tesseract: for instance **tesseract-ocr-chi-sim (Simplified Chinese)**. List of languages: [list](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata)

```
docker exec -it tika-server-ocr /bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get install tesseract-ocr-chi-s
```

Then You need to enable OCR (for pdf parsing) an set the Chinese as a language:

```
curl -H "X-Tika-PDFextractInlineImages: true" -H "X-Tika-PDFocrStrategy: OCR_ONLY" -H "X-Tika-OCRLanguage: chi-sim"  -T test.pdf localhost:9998/tika
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey welcome to the Stack Overflow society.
It is possible that the Chinese fonts aren't installed in the Adobe Reader.
You can install them from this [link](https://supportdownloads.adobe.com/product.jsp?product=10&platform=Windows) (scroll to the section called Add-Ons). There are two font packs available. You can try installing these and let me know how this goes.
Regards,
Truly Amazing Vidoes by Ravi Arora

Comment: Hi Ravi, thank you for your comment, it made me realise my question was unclear. The issue I want to resolve is with Tika for Python parsing the text correctly and not Acrobat. I was just using Acrobat to show what was going wrong with the PDF and have now edited the question.

Comment: @Moonman157 The problem with Tika might have to be resolved similarly, you may have to configure it (or the underlying PDFBox) to access some extra fonts. As you don't share the PDF in question, though, we can only guess. Aside from missing fonts a defect in the PDF might also cause this behavior (fixed under the hood by Chrome but not by others) or an encoding mismatch between components used in your setup.

Comment: @mkl I have added links to the PDF now, thanks for mentioning that. The issue with the document is that the name of the embedded font is also garbled, so I can't manually add the missing fonts. Or do you mean that I can add a font that supports CJK characters for PDFBox to use by default?

Comment: *"For CJK (Chinese, Japanese, and Korean) fonts, the host font system’s font name is often encoded in the host operating system’s script. For instance, a Japanese font may have a name that is written in Japanese using some (unidentified) Japanese encoding. Thus, TrueType font names may contain multiple-byte character codes, each of which requires multiple characters to represent in a PDF name object (using the # notation to quote special characters as needed)."* (ISO 32000-1, section 9.6.3, NOTE 4) - Thus, the name of the font may be garbled because it uses an unknown encoding.